# Ajax call is not being invoked from jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to invoke jquery ajax rest service call on jsp page load but having hard time making it working.. I don't see anything wrong with the following code i'm using.
Any suggestions around would be appreciated

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() { 
    var thisUrl = 'http://wwwtest.env.tree.org/url/api/filters/1234';
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : thisUrl,
       dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
           alert('data is:' + data);
           $("#customText").text(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call you are making is cross domain. To get it working

1. you should have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `*` or the `domain name` from which you are making this ajax call. How to set this attribute on different servers is [discussed here](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).
2. jquery ajax call make sure `crossDomain` atribute set to true. Supported Jquery > 1.5.
   read more about it [in docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
3. Jquery cross domain ajax call wont work in old IE browsers, so to get it working you should use some fix. [The discussion](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cross-domain-ajax-and-ie) about the same and fixes could be [found here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cross-domain-ajax-and-ie).

Answer (score 0):

Instead try this,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
alert('ready'); //To check whether ready function works
var thisUrl = 'http://wwwtest.env.tree.org/url/api/filters/1234';
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : thisUrl,
   dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data) {
       alert('data is:' + data);
       $("#customText").text(data);
    }
});
});
```

Also check your console by using developer tools (like firebug) whether it is giving correct response. Make sure that you are having latest jQuery.js in your header path before calling this function.